# Upgrading magento 2.3.6 to 2.4.5 its running in php8.1

Tags: magento-upgrade, setup-di-compile, magento2.4.5

Already run the setup:upgrade command it's working fine,
but now when I am running the setup:di:compile command, it's giving the below error message.

> Repositories code generation... 1/9 [===>------------------------]
> 11% < 1 sec 48.0 MiBsyntax error, unexpected token "", expecting
> variable#0 /home/site/www/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(322):
> Composer\Autoload\includeFile()

please provide your suggestion and guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has dependencies on Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql* classes.

Support of the Mysql search adapter was deprecated in 2.3 and removed in 2.4.

Please review your code/customization and remove these dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that there is a syntax error in one of the PHP files being loaded by the Composer autoloader. This error may be related to the upgrade to PHP 8.1, as some code that was previously valid in older versions of PHP may no longer be valid.

To troubleshoot this issue, you can try the following steps:

1. Check the PHP error log for more details on the error. The error log may provide more context on the file and line number where the error occurred, which can help you pinpoint the issue.
2. Disable all third-party modules and try running the code generation again. If the error disappears, then the issue is likely related to a third-party module. You can then enable the modules one by one to isolate the one causing the error.
3. Check the PHP syntax in all custom code to ensure that it is compatible with PHP 8.1. You can use a syntax checker tool or the php -l command to validate the syntax of your PHP files.
4. Ensure that all third-party modules and dependencies are compatible with PHP 8.1. You can check the documentation and release notes for each module and dependency to confirm compatibility with PHP 8.1.
5. If the issue persists, you can try updating the Composer autoloader by running composer dump-autoload in the Magento root directory. This command will regenerate the Composer autoloader files and may resolve any issues related to autoloading.